# Replace misspelled values with agrep

Tags: r, replace, subset, misspelling, agrep

I have a dataset of restaurants and the variable "CONAME" contains the name of each establishment. Unfortunately, there are quite a few misspellings, and I'd like to correct them. I've tried agrep for fuzzy set matching using the following code (which I'll repeat for all major chains):

> rest2012$CONAME <- agrep("MC DONALD'S", rest2012$CONAME, ignore.case = FALSE, value = FALSE, max.distance = 3)

I'm getting the following error message:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "CONAME", value = c(35L, 40L, 48L,  : 
  replacement has 3074 rows, data has 67424

Is there another way I can replace the misspelled names or am I simply using the agrep function wrong?

Comment: Read the error message. You are trying to replace the **entire** column (67424 items) with just the ones that are misspelled (3074).

Comment: @user2868256, did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `agrep` with `value = FALSE` the result is "a vector giving the indices of the elements that yielded a match". That is, the position of matches in the vector of names that you fed `agrep` with. You then try to replace the *entire **name** variable* in your data frame (67424 rows) with a *shorter vector of **indices*** (3074 of them). Not what you want. Here is a small example which perhaps can guide you in the right direction. You may also read `?Extract` and [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html). The details of `agrep` itself (e.g. `max.distance`), I leave to you.

```
# create a data frame with some MC DONALD's-ish names, and some other names.
rest2012 <- data.frame(CONAME = c("MC DONALD'S", "MCC DONALD'S", "SPSS Café", "GLM RONALDO'S", "MCMCglmm"))
rest2012

# do some fuzzy matching with 'agrep'
# store the indices in an object named 'idx'
idx <- agrep(pattern = "MC DONALD'S", x = rest2012$CONAME, ignore.case = FALSE, value = FALSE, max.distance = 3)
idx

# just look at the rows in the data frame that matched
# indexing with a numeric vector 
rest2012[idx, ]

# replace the elements that matches 
rest2012[idx, ] <- "MC DONALD'S"
rest2012
```